# Cannot update global variable from Ajax call in jQuery more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load additional articles when user gets to the bottom of the page. I have all things implemented, but can't increment global variable in JavaScript that I use more than once. I'd be less surprised if it didn't work at all, but this way...
Anyway, I have already forced `async:false` and it still doesn't work as expected - *start variable* gets incremented to 1 with first call and then it's always 1 after each next call.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

```
start = 0;

function LoadNextArticles()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax/articles_load.php",
        data: "start=" + start,
        async: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            c = $("#content").html();
            $("#content").html(c + msg);

            start += 1;             
        }
    });
}

setInterval(function() {    
    if  ( ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop() < 10 )
    {
        LoadNextArticles();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is just generally all a bad idea, checking the scrolled position every second instead of when the user actually scrolls, using **Asynchronous** Javascript And XML in a synchronous manner etc.

Comment: BTW, try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/3wE3W/

Comment: The AJAX response: Does it contain a script tag, that sets `start` back to 0?

Comment: why do you want it to be syncronous. It seems to be a perfect candidate for async. Where is the above code placed? in an event handler such as document ready or in another function or stand alone? Where are you using start except for the two places in the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

1. document.start += 1
2. try add 'context' variable to your ajax call

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       context: this, 
       ...

or maybe context: document

Comment: Variables in a higher scope is available in lower scopes, no reason for the window or document as a namespace or passing context ?

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with your code, but try `window.start` instead of `start`
Also, `async:false` is bad idea, it'll pause javascript execution until your request completes.

More on global variables:
http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable